# DirectX 11: Почему в DirectX 11 не получается поставить формат DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT для SwapChain?

Tags: c++, directx, format

Вопрос получился очень большим, так что основная суть:
Когда для заднего буфера я пытаюсь поставить формат DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT появляется ошибка:

"Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. DX::swapChain было nullptr."

```
//Дальше идёт подробнее о проблеме
```

Я делаю трассировку путей, для этого мне нужно было создать накопление цвета в какую-либо текстуру.
Для этого я рендерю изображение на задний буфер, потом с помощью метода CopyResource() копирую изображение на текстуру, которую потом использую в шейдере с помощью shaderResourceView. Всё работало относительно отлично, но накопление происходило до определённого момента, секунд так 10.

Вот максимальный результат, которого удаётся добиться(рендерил 10 мин). Как видите, шума просто предостаточно:
[image: Изображение с форматом DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM]
Похоже проблема в том, что я использую не тот формат для заднего буфера, и текстуры, в которую я копирую информацию из заднего буфера(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM).
В шейдере есть такое выражение:

```
        result.x = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).x, result.x, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
        result.y = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).y, result.y, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
        result.z = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).z, result.z, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
```

(1 / input.samplesCount.y) - это коэффициент интерполяции, с каждой итерацией input.samplesCount.y инкрементируется(увеличивается на 1), следовательно число (1 / input.samplesCount.y) становится меньше.

Result - это переменная, которая подаётся на выход(то есть итоговый цвет)

```
        return float4(result, 1);
```

Я предполагаю, что из за того, что у меня стоит формат DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, выходное значение как то округляется, но в какой то момент, значение становится на столько маленьким, что результат сложение не влияет на итоговый цвет.

Я попробовал поставить другой формат(DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT), но когда я его устанавливаю на задний буфер, то приложение просто не запускается, при этом выдаёт ошибку:

"Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. DX::swapChain было nullptr."
Вот код инициализации SwapChain(комментарием помечено место возникновения ошибки):

```
bool DX::Init(HWND OutputWindow, UINT backBufferWidth, UINT backBufferHeight)
{
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC saidChainDesc{};
    saidChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    saidChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    //saidChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM;
    saidChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    saidChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = backBufferWidth;
    saidChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = backBufferHeight;
    saidChainDesc.OutputWindow = OutputWindow;
    saidChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    saidChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
    saidChainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
    saidChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL;
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain
    (
        NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &saidChainDesc,
        &DX::swapChain,
        &DX::device,
        NULL,
        &DX::deviceCon
    );
    DX::swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferTexture);
    // Тут ошибка  DX::swapChain было nullptr."
    DX::device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferTexture, NULL, &DX::backRenderTargetView);
    // Тут ошибка  DX::swapChain было nullptr."
    DX::deviceCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &DX::backRenderTargetView, NULL);
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport{};
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = backBufferWidth;
    viewport.Height = backBufferHeight;
    DX::deviceCon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
    return false;
}
```

Хотя формат DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT работает, но при этом само изображение в трассироке путей начинает во первых становится каким то тусклым, а со временем темнеет, и преобретает какие то странные цвета(ощущение, как будто бензин пролили на воду):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема? Буду очень благодарен если вы поможете.

P.S. Как это всё должно работать:
Я рисую изображение на задний буфер, при этом, результат смешиваю с текстурой, на которую записан предыдущий результат работы шейдера.
Вот код в шейдере:

```
        result.x = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).x, result.x, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
        result.y = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).y, result.y, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
        result.z = Lerp(objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord).z, result.z, 1 / input.samplesCount.y);
```

objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.textureCoord) - это текстура, на которую скопирован результат, с предыдущей итерации.
Вот код копирования:

```
        samplesCount.x = samplesAmount;
        samplesCount.y++;
        CorrectScreenResolution();
        BindButtons();
        HideOrShowCursor();

        SetRandomValue();
        Moving();
        setConstantData();
        samplerState->Set(0, 1);
        //shaderResource->Set(0, 1);
        //Sleep(1000);
        SetTextures();
        Shape::Draw();
        if (k.w == 0)
        {
            DX::deviceCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &DX::backRenderTargetView, NULL);
            DX::deviceCon->CopyResource(texture, DX::backBufferTexture);
            //k.y = 0;
        }
```

Как видите, после отрисовки (Shape::Draw()), я выполняю копирование результат, отрисованный на задний буфер, в текстуру:

```
            DX::deviceCon->CopyResource(texture, DX::backBufferTexture);
```

Comment: Основная проблема в приведенном коде - полное отсутствие проверок успешности вызовов. Что касается форматов, то `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT`, да и fp формат половинной точности, совсем не обязательно поддерживаются в качестве формата буфера. Рендерите в текстуру, а уже потом - в буфер. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/checking-hardware-feature-support

Comment: @user7860670 я не знаю что означает формат с половинной точности(похоже float). Что не так с этим форматом? А методом ID3D11Device :: CheckFormatSupport я уже проверял совместимость формата DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, но в итоге HRESULT ни разу не вернул неудачу. Я так понял что задний буфер не поддерживает  DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT. Про то, что вы предлагаете рендерить в текстуру, а потом в буфер, вы возможно не поняли то, зачем я рендерю в буфер, а потом копирую в текстуру. Я поправлю текст, и объясню конкретнее.

Comment: Формат половинной точности - это DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT. Суть в том, что буфер у swap chain поддерживает форматы подходящие для вывода на экран. В задний буфер я предлагаю рендерить только при выводе изображения на экран. А до этого - только в текстуру. При этом для хранения результата предыдущей итерации нужно будет использовать еще одну текстуру, а потом менять их ролями ничего не копируя.

Comment: а это не ответ, это все комментарии

Comment: Ты увидел, что я удалял XD. Сорри, пытаюсь написать, и случайно нажимаю enter, чтобы перейти на следующую строчку, и случайно отправляю, не дописав. Так и думал, что это комменты. Почему же ты тогда не написал в ответы, я бы тебя отметил. Но в любом случае, я увидел кнопку, ответить на свой вопрос, если ты не решишь переписать вопрос туда(что врдяли, хотя ты можешь получить быллы). Надо же помогать людям, с примерно такой же проблемой :3

Comment: а я не знаю ответа... "не получается, так как DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT не поддерживается" - это какой-то слишком капитанский ответ

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) за ответ.
Так я до конца и не понял, но похоже, нельзя устанавливать формат DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT на задний буфер. В любом случае, то что я хотел, я исправил, и теперь изображение может улучшаться до без шумного результата.

Теперь шума абсолютно нету.
Кому интересно что получилось: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше я рендерил изображение в задний буфер, и затем копировал изображение в текстуру, которую использовал для накопления(сохранял результат предыдущей итерации, чтобы использовать его при следующей отрисовке).
Поэтому качество моего изображения завело напрямую от заднего буфера, и из за балой битности цветовых каналов, в какой то момент изменения в картинке становились на столько маленькими, что они не влияли на результат.

Я немного поменял работу кода. Теперь вместо того, чтобы рендерить изображение на задний буфер, и потом копировать оттуда данные в текстуру, я создал две текстуры, и рендерю изображение на одну из текстур, в то время как другая текстура выступает шейдерным ресурсом(эту другою текстуру я использую в шейдере).

```
    ID3D11Texture2D* texture[2]; // 2 текстуры
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* textureRenderTarget[2]; // 2 рендер торгета для текстур, для того чтобы в них можно было рендерить
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* shaderResourceView[2]; // 2 шейдер ресурса, для того, чтобы их можно было использовать как ресурс в шейдере
```

Я рисую в первую текстуру изображение (устанавливаю её как цель рендеринга), и смешиваю со второй текстурой(использую шейдерный ресурс, привязанный ко второй текстуре).

```
    DX::deviceCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &textureRenderTarget[textureQueue], NULL); // Ставлю текстуру, под индексом 0 
    // textureQueue - булевая переменная, textureQueue = FALSE равнасильно textureQueue = 0, поэтому выбирается текстура под индексом 0
```

После этого я выполняю промежуточные действия, которые не важны для объяснения, и затем привязываю шейдерный ресурс

```
    DX::deviceCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &shaderResourceView[!textureQueue]);
    //!textureQueue - значит другая текстура, в данной случае
    //textureQueue = FALSE, !textureQueue  = TRUE следовательно
    //это шейдерный ресурс текстуры под идексом 1


    Shape::Draw(shaderRayTracing);
```

Затем указываю как цель рендеринга задний буфер, используя уже другой шейдер, который предназначен для того, чтобы поставить текстуру на какую-то геометрию(в моём случае просто квадрат, заполняющий весь экран). Этой текстурой и будет являться та, первая текстура, в которую я нарисовал изображение

```
    DX::deviceCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &DX::backRenderTargetView, NULL);
    samplerState->Set(0, 1);
    DX::deviceCon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &shaderResourceView[textureQueue]);
    Shape::Draw(shaderTexturing); //  рисую изображение на задний буфер(на экран по сути)
    //shaderTexturing - тот самый шейдер для рисования
    //текстур на какой-либо геометрии
```

После всех действий, я меняю местами индексы:

```
    textureQueue = !textureQueue; // Теперь textureQueue = TRUE
    // следовательно, там, где я устанавливал как цель рендеринга текстуру под индексом 
    //0(FALSE), будет ставится текстура, под индексом 1(TRUE), ну и так далее
```

Задача конечно довольно специфичная, но надеюсь я кому-то помогу этим ответом :3

И дальше напишу кое что не по теме:

Спасибо user7860670 за ответ. Если честно, то я ожидал, что после моего второго вопроса, он налетит на меня с сарказмами, и послёт куда подальше, или просто про игнорит. Но нет, он просто спокойно ответил и помог, что не обычно как по мне(может для stackoverflow это обычно конечно?). Хотя в основном я вспоминаю mail ответы, боже, никогда там ничего не задавайте. Хотя на кибер форуме тоже норм). Зачем я это написал?